# Anaconda installation messed up the existing Python packages

Tags: python, anaconda, bitbucket

For my project requirements I had installed Python packages like Jira and Bitbucket to connect to the servers using their API wrappers. After I installed Anaconda all the existing packages stopped working. Now Im getting No Module Found error for both Bitbucket and JIRA although the modules are already installed

For example :

pip3 install bitbucket-python

gives me that requirement is already satisfied. But when I run the code I get:

No module named "bitbucket" found

The same code was running fine 2 days ago before I installed anaconda.

Please help.

Comment: My first guess is that Anaconda has changed your default python distribution. Can you check if you have several python versions installed?

Comment: python --version gives me
Python 3.7.6

Comment: I ran where python command and it gave me 3 separate paths for python.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have different versions of python and pip in your system. You have to make sure you are running correct version of the command. In my system with conda installed and activated pip3 refers to pip for system python. and pip for active conda python.

Try this: `pip install bitbucket-python`

you can use `which` command to see which binary is getting executed for example on my system.

```
dhananjay@ideapad:~$ which python
/home/dhananjay/.conda/bin/python

dhananjay@ideapad:~$ which pip
/home/dhananjay/.conda/bin/pip

dhananjay@ideapad:~$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Comment: My issue got resolved after Try this: pip install bitbucket-python. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I have a question. How can I use my old python environment now? If I dont want to use the anaconda version of packages what should I do

Comment: either you can deactivate conda and then python will refer to you system python or you can use complete path to system python binary for example in my case `/usr/bin/python`. also do mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: sure. Thanks. One last help, How do I deactivate and activate Conda

Comment: the command is `conda deactivate`  This deactivates the conda for current terminal session i.e. for all commands run after this. [ref](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment)